# Twitter intent's 'tweet' event callback triggering on 'click' instead of 'tweet'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, share

I have some issue with twitter intent share functionality, the "tweet" event triggered on click the share button itself(before opening the popup). I have checked the "click" and "tweet" events and both events are triggered simultaneously.

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind(
        'click',
    twitter_share_callback);
    twttr.events.bind(
        'tweet',
    twitter_share_callback);

});


function twitter_share_callback(response) {
    console.log(response)
    $("#response").append(response.type+"<br>")
    //code
}
```

The working example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chingsu/2djbg2re/)

I Wish to get the "tweet" callback right after successfull tweet.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i was able to find the reason behind the issue

From November 20th twitter will be making a change to the tweet, follow, retweet and favorite JavaScript events when using Twitter for Websites. They will now be triggered when a user invokes the action in your page, rather than after the action is completed.

For more info https://twittercommunity.com/t/forthcoming-change-to-web-intent-events/54718

Comment: any workaround to know if someone really tweet something?

Comment: At present there is no workaround for JS API, but with OAuth2 its possible. Reffer https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: @JinsSebastian Hi. Can are you share your solution?

Comment: @JinsSebastian I too would love to know a viable solution using OAuth2 as I am in the same boat

Comment: Hi @JinsSebastian did you got the solution for above

Comment: You can use the retweet functionality from Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/web-intents/overview#tweet-or-reply