# Can we detect if page shared on Twitter and LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, linkedin-api

I am designing an Ecommerce website in PHP, on product page there is Twitter and LinkedIn share button, if user shares that product page than he will get $5 discount. Now my query is how can I detect if that product/page successfully shared on Twitter or LinkedIn, so I can apply that discount. Is there any response Twitter or LinkedIn return if url shared successfully.

Comment: Be warned, it will be trivial for a user to post a message, get the discount, then delete the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite old, so for people who stumble upon it in the future:

From November 20, 2015, Twitter changed the behavior of the 'tweet' event so that it is no longer possible to track actual tweets. An alternative could be the OAuth API.

[Twitter intent's 'tweet' event callback triggering on 'click' instead of 'tweet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950630/twitter-intents-tweet-event-callback-triggering-on-click-instead-of-tweet)

Answer (score 0):

for **twitter**, [they got API for events](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events), it's kind of simple with JS:

```
twttr.events.bind(
  'tweet',
  function (event) {
    // Do something there, for example send notification
  }
);
```

for **linkedIn**, they also gotten the rich API for such the things, choose the method you'd like here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin