# Twitter share popup successful responds

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, callback, share

I have these share popups on my website where the user can share our page. This is what I actually want: Check when the user successfully(callback or response) shared the post.

I found the following solutions: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948130/10347490).
But this only triggers on `tweet` event, the `tweet` event is triggered at the same as the `click` event, so this isn't the way. Is there a way to check if they actually shared it?

**UPDATE:** I have tried checking if the Streaming API from Twitter could help me out with this. But it only gives me the posted tweets after minutes. It should be executed immediately. So this isn't an option either.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** None of my workarounds are useful

What I do for Facebook, this works:

```
function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {

    } else {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function shareFacebook() {

    FB.init({
        appId: 'apiid',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'share',
            href: 'google.com'
        },
        // callback
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error_message) {
                alert('shared!')
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is the problem, but there is no solution?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950630/twitter-intents-tweet-event-callback-triggering-on-click-instead-of-tweet?rq=1

Comment: Still didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link you posted. Use the twitter js widgets and the intents api shown in your link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932354/10934956.

This is not just for listening to when the window closes, as you stated. There are specific event listeners that you can subscribe to, such as loaded, rendered, resize, tweet, follow, retweet, like, and click.

You could add a listener to the `tweet` event and insert your callback, just like the link I provided does.

If you are stuck with getting a callback only when the window closes, you could potentially evaluate the URL of the event to see if was on a completed Tweet URL. This would, of course, not be 100% reliable.

**Edit:** Without using this widget, there is no way to add a callback to a different tab/browser for security reason. Even tabs in the same browser are kept completely independent so that site `A` can't read anything on site `B` where you could potentially put in vital information.

Comment: The problem here is that the `tweet` event is triggered at the same time as the `click` event. So checking if the tweet is actually done doesn't work. https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-intent-response-the-same-for-successful-and-unsuccessful-posts/56780/8